# Dispaying whole array once in matlab

Tags: matlab

I've just started learning matlab and was writing this simple code:

```
A= rand(7,1);
fprintf('value is:%f',A);
```

the answer displayed was:

value is:0.083591value is:0.932224value is:0.679920value is:0.591426value is:0.024818value is:0.519600value is:0.481866

What should I do to display all values together......

Comment: Have you tried `disp(A)` ?

Comment: Do you want "Value is: " or just the values? If so, any reason you can't just do: `A`? It will output the entire array if you don't use a `;` after it.

Comment: Note that the `A` you describe would typically be referred to as a *matrix* or a *vector* in order to avoid letting people think that your array is actually a *cell array*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Dennis' answer, if you actually want to output some text in front of the values, you can do the following:

```
disp('The values are:')
disp(A)
The values are:
    0.0357
    0.8491
    0.9340
    0.6787
    0.7577
    0.7431
    0.3922
```

or, if you want "The value is: " in front of every single number, you can do use `fprintf` as you tried, but with a slight adjustment. Notice the `\n` which gives you a line break.

```
fprintf('The value is: %f \n', A);
The value is: 0.035712 
The value is: 0.849129 
The value is: 0.933993 
The value is: 0.678735 
The value is: 0.757740 
The value is: 0.743132 
The value is: 0.392227
```

or even:

```
fprintf('Value nr. %i is %f \n',[(1:numel(A)); A.']);
Value nr. 1 is 0.035712 
Value nr. 2 is 0.849129 
Value nr. 3 is 0.933993 
Value nr. 4 is 0.678735 
Value nr. 5 is 0.757740 
Value nr. 6 is 0.743132 
Value nr. 7 is 0.392227
```

*But*, if you actually only want to see the values, this can be achieved by not suppressing the output with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

As @luis Mendo mentioned you could use the following:

```
disp(A)
```

However, only slightly different, and even simpler would be:

```
A
```

That being said, as mentioned by @Robert P. you could also just not suppress the output when you create the matrix (if your real situation is as simple as the example). In this case your code would just be:

```
A= rand(7,1)
```